# Treat with the two last digits (dd) of each row in a 'date' (yyyymmdd) column in Pandas df

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to treat an entire column of date values to change it in a column of numbers from "1" to "the last day of the month" in a Pandas dataframe.
The code has to be able to deal with columns of 28,29,30 or 31 values depending on which month is concerned.
So my df:

```
        DAY      TX     TN
0   20190201    4.9     -0.6
1   20190202    2.7     0.0
2   20190203    4.6     -0.3
3   20190204    2.9     -0.5
4   20190205    6.2     1.3
5   20190206    7.5     2.4
6   20190207    8.6     4.6
7   20190208    8.6     5.0
8   20190209    9.2     6.7
9   20190210    9.1     3.8
10  20190211    6.9     0.7
11  20190212    7.0     -0.5
12  20190213    7.8     -0.5
13  20190214    13.4    0.0
14  20190215    16.4    2.0
15  20190216    14.8    2.0
16  20190217    15.7    1.2
17  20190218    15.4    1.2
18  20190219    9.8     4.3
19  20190220    11.1    2.8
20  20190221    13.1    5.8
21  20190222    10.7    4.1
22  20190223    12.9    1.5
23  20190224    14.5    1.2
24  20190225    16.1    2.2
25  20190226    17.2    0.3
26  20190227    19.3    1.1
27  20190228    11.3    5.1
```

should become

```
   DAY   TX     TN
0   1   4.9     -0.6
1   2   2.7     0.0
2   3   4.6     -0.3
3   4   2.9     -0.5
4   5   6.2     1.3
5   6   7.5     2.4
6   7   8.6     4.6
7   8   8.6     5.0
8   9   9.2     6.7
9   10  9.1     3.8
10  11  6.9     0.7
11  12  7.0     -0.5
12  13  7.8     -0.5
13  14  13.4    0.0
14  15  16.4    2.0
15  16  14.8    2.0
16  17  15.7    1.2
17  18  15.4    1.2
18  19  9.8     4.3
19  20  11.1    2.8
20  21  13.1    5.8
21  22  10.7    4.1
22  23  12.9    1.5
23  24  14.5    1.2
24  25  16.1    2.2
25  26  17.2    0.3
26  27  19.3    1.1
27  28  11.3    5.1
```

I have to treat each value of this column so I can also check that there is no day missing and that the generation of numbers adapts to each month-df I will provide.
I searched in the Pandas documentation for an instruction that could help but I didn't find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `df['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.day
```

Another solution is casting values to strings, get last 2 integers by indexing and cast to integers:

```
df['DAY'] = df['DAY'].astype(str).str[-2:].astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
    DAY    TX   TN
0     1   4.9 -0.6
1     2   2.7  0.0
2     3   4.6 -0.3
3     4   2.9 -0.5
4     5   6.2  1.3
5     6   7.5  2.4
6     7   8.6  4.6
7     8   8.6  5.0
8     9   9.2  6.7
9    10   9.1  3.8
10   11   6.9  0.7
11   12   7.0 -0.5
12   13   7.8 -0.5
13   14  13.4  0.0
14   15  16.4  2.0
15   16  14.8  2.0
16   17  15.7  1.2
17   18  15.4  1.2
18   19   9.8  4.3
19   20  11.1  2.8
20   21  13.1  5.8
21   22  10.7  4.1
22   23  12.9  1.5
23   24  14.5  1.2
24   25  16.1  2.2
25   26  17.2  0.3
26   27  19.3  1.1
27   28  11.3  5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just slice the column to get the last 2 digits and cast to `int`:

```
In[85]:
df['DAY'] = df['DAY'].str[-2:].astype(int)
df

Out[85]: 
    DAY    TX   TN
0     1   4.9 -0.6
1     2   2.7  0.0
2     3   4.6 -0.3
3     4   2.9 -0.5
4     5   6.2  1.3
5     6   7.5  2.4
6     7   8.6  4.6
7     8   8.6  5.0
8     9   9.2  6.7
9    10   9.1  3.8
10   11   6.9  0.7
11   12   7.0 -0.5
12   13   7.8 -0.5
13   14  13.4  0.0
14   15  16.4  2.0
15   16  14.8  2.0
16   17  15.7  1.2
17   18  15.4  1.2
18   19   9.8  4.3
19   20  11.1  2.8
20   21  13.1  5.8
21   22  10.7  4.1
22   23  12.9  1.5
23   24  14.5  1.2
24   25  16.1  2.2
25   26  17.2  0.3
26   27  19.3  1.1
27   28  11.3  5.1
```

If the `dtype` is `int` already then you just need to cast to `str` first:

```
df['DAY'] = df['DAY'].astype(str).str[-2:].astype(int)
```

Comment: `df['DAY'].astype(str).str[-2:].astype(int)` may be necessary... unclear from OP's sample data

Comment: @ChrisA - In my answer :)

Comment: @ChrisA yes, true

Comment: yes 'DAY' is already integer (my sample df is not properly wrote here)
How can I insert correctly the sample dataframe in the statement of my question for next time ?
I've wrote it manually here with the triple ` but there is certainly a better way to do it

Comment: Sorry are you saying my answer doesn't work? It should if 'DAY' is already an int